# How to call a method from navbar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to call a method from navbar, when I call the object the image has been selected not appears in the screen.

My goal is to do this, when I Click in Gallery and select new image, show this like in Screen 2.

[image: First screen to select way to choose the image]

[image: The screen that I want to show when I selected the photo]

The code for this interactions,

```
  File imageFile;

  _openGallery(BuildContext context) async{
    var picture = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source:ImageSource.gallery);
    this.setState((){
      imageFile = picture;
    });
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }


  _openCamera(BuildContext context) async{
    var picture = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source:ImageSource.camera);
    this.setState((){
      imageFile = picture;
    });
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
```

And the build widget

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(


        body: Container(
          child: Center(
              child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: <Widget>[
                _decideImageView(),
                RaisedButton(onPressed: (){
                  _showChoiceDialog(context);
                },child: Text('Select Image'),),
                _decideButton(context)

              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),

        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type:BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        onTap: (int index) {
          if (index==0)
            _openGallery(context);
          if (index == 1)
            _openCamera(context);
        },
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.photo_library),
            title: Text('Home')
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
            title: Text('Camera')
          ),
         ],
      ),

    );
  }
```

The function to decide if you will see a text asking for select a image or return the image on the screen is this one below, the method is called _decideImageView.

```
  Widget _decideImageView(){
    if(imageFile == null){
      return Text('Kein Bild ausgewählt',
       style: TextStyle(
                                    color:Colors.black,
                                    fontFamily: 'Lato', 
                                    fontSize: 25,
                                    letterSpacing: 1.0
                                    ),          );
    }
    else{

      return Image.file(imageFile,width:400,height:400);
    }
  }
```

Comment: what's the problem? do you receive any error on your implementation? anyways as i see you don't update your selected bottombaritem color when you selected it but that's a minor thing.

Comment: The image  is not showed on the screen when I select. I didn't receive any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove this: Navigator.of(context).pop();
 on the two ways to pick the picture, that's work for me, but you need to know that's not the best way to create an image picker.

Comment: worked for me, What is the best way to create this?